# unit tests for command line args python

Tags: python, python-2.7, shell, unit-testing, pytest

I have a shell script which currently takes 3 args. I run this via a shell script with the shell script file name , a directory to run the python script upon , along with the name of the test data directory. I want to be able to write a unit tests which executes the command below but only if i was to change the date , depending on the data that is available it would either pass or fail.

```
main_config.sh
```

```bash
yamldir=$1

for yaml in $(ls ${yamldir}/*.yaml | grep -v "export_config.yaml"); do

    if [ "$yaml" != "export_config.yaml" ]; then

        echo "Running export for $yaml file...";
        python valid.py -p ${yamldir}/export_config.yaml -e $yaml -d ${endDate}
        wait

    fi

done
```

This is what is executed on the command line

```
./main_config.sh /Users/name/Desktop/yaml/ 2018-12-23
```

This will fail and output on the terminal since there is no directory called 2012-12-23 :

```
./main_config.sh /yaml/ 2018-12-23
    Running export for apa.yaml file...
    apa.json does not exist
```

If the directory existed this would pass and would output on the terminal :

```
Running export for apa.yaml file...
File Name: apa.json Exists 
File Size: 234 Bytes 
Writing to file
```

My python script script is as follows :

```
def main(get_config):
    cfg = get_config()[0]  # export_config.yaml
    data = get_config()[1]  # export_apa.yaml
    date = get_config()[2]  # data folder - YYYY-MM-DD

# Conditional Logic


def get_config():
    parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
    parser.add_argument("-p", "--parameter-file", action="store", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-e", "--export-data-file", action="store", required=True)
    parser.add_argument("-d", "--export-date", action="store", required=False)
    args = parser.parse_args()

    return [funcs.read_config(args.parameter_file), funcs.read_config(args.export_data_file), args.export_date]


if __name__ == "__main__":
    logging.getLogger().setLevel(logging.INFO)
    main(get_config)
```

Comment: Can you be more specific? What's giving you trouble with writing the tests?

Comment: It's more of the approach of writing the tests. The logic. I have been doing some reading but this is not testing a function but more an integration test. @JETM

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks like this is not a typical unit test (that tests a function or method) but an integration test (that tests a subsystem from the outside). But of course you could still solve this with your typical Python testing tools like `unittest`.

A simple solution would be to run your script using `subprocess`, capture the output, and then parse that output as part of your test:

```
import unittest

import os
import sys
if os.name == 'posix' and sys.version_info[0] < 3:
    import subprocess32 as subprocess
else:
    import subprocess

class TestScriptInvocation(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        """call the script and record its output"""
        result = subprocess.run(["./main_config.sh", "/Users/yasserkhan/Desktop/yaml/", "2018-12-23"], stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
        self.returncode = result.returncode
        self.output_lines = result.stdout.decode('utf-8').split('\n')

    def test_returncode(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.returncode, 0)

    def test_last_line_indicates_success(self):
        self.assertEqual(self.output_lines[-1], 'Writing to file')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

Note that this code uses the backport of the Python 3 `subprocess` module. Also, it tries to decode the contents of `result.stdout` because on Python 3 that would be a `bytes` object and not a `str` as on Python 2. I didn't test it, but these two things should make the code portable between 2 and 3.

Also note that using absolute paths like `"/Users/yasserkhan/Desktop/yaml"` could easily break, so you will either need to find a relative path or pass a base path to your tests using environment variables for example.

You could add additional tests that parse the other lines and check for reasonable outputs like a file size in the expected range.